# What will the comprehension equivalent be for the following snippet of coad?

Tags: for-comprehension

for sentence in paragraph:     for word in sentence.split(): Single_word_list.append(word)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent list comprehension is:

```py
[Single_word_list.append(word) for word in sentence.split() for sentence in paragraph]
```

This arguably suffers in readability compared to nested for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[Single_word_list.append(word) for word in sentence.split()] for sentence in paragraph]
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)

Edit: Here's without nested list comprehention

```
[Single_word_list.append(word) for sentence in paragraph for word in sentence.split()]
```